# Child process: The stdout parameter

Tags: node.js

According to the docs, the `child_process.exec` command's callback's `stdout` parameter should be of a `Buffer` type.

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

The problem is that it isn't:

```
var exec, child;
exec = require('child_process').exec;

child = exec('/bin/echo -n "hello"', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("error!");
        return;
    }
    console.log("isBuffer: " + Buffer.isBuffer(stdout));
    console.log("type: " + typeof stdout);
});
```

This prints

```
isBuffer: false
type: string
```

Why? Is this a documentation bug?

This is a **major problem** because if there is binary data in `stdout`, I get the incorrect data out. Putting `{encoding: 'binary'}` into options did not help.

Comment: What Node.js version are you running?

Comment: @Brad The latest, 0.10.18.

Comment: this will be fixed in 0.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [node.js source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.18/lib/child_process.js#L613) shows that, as of 0.10.18, stdout is always a string. If you want to get binary data, you have to use `spawn`.

However, it seems like node.js 0.12 will introduce an option to get binary data if you pass `{encoding: 'buffer'}`:

(https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/child_process.js#L617):

```
if (options.encoding !== 'buffer' && Buffer.isEncoding(options.encoding)) {
```

**EDIT**: code example was taken from master and is not in stable version yet.

**EDIT 2**: Here's a backported version of the version of `exec` which will accept the buffer encoding:

```
var util = require('util'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var exec = function(command /*, options, callback */) {
  var file, args, options, callback;

  if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
    options = undefined;
    callback = arguments[1];
  } else {
    options = arguments[1];
    callback = arguments[2];
  }

  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    file = 'cmd.exe';
    args = ['/s', '/c', '"' + command + '"'];
    // Make a shallow copy before patching so we don't clobber the user's
    // options object.
    options = util._extend({}, options);
    options.windowsVerbatimArguments = true;
  } else {
    file = '/bin/sh';
    args = ['-c', command];
  }

  if (options && options.shell)
    file = options.shell;

  return execFile(file, args, options, callback);
};


var execFile = function(file /* args, options, callback */) {
  var args, callback;
  var options = {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    timeout: 0,
    maxBuffer: 200 * 1024,
    killSignal: 'SIGTERM',
    cwd: null,
    env: null
  };

  // Parse the parameters.

  if (typeof(arguments[arguments.length - 1]) === 'function') {
    callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
  }

  if (util.isArray(arguments[1])) {
    args = arguments[1];
    options = util._extend(options, arguments[2]);
  } else {
    args = [];
    options = util._extend(options, arguments[1]);
  }

  var child = spawn(file, args, {
    cwd: options.cwd,
    env: options.env,
    windowsVerbatimArguments: !!options.windowsVerbatimArguments
  });

  var encoding;
  var _stdout;
  var _stderr;
  if (options.encoding !== 'buffer' && Buffer.isEncoding(options.encoding)) {
    encoding = options.encoding;
    _stdout = '';
    _stderr = '';
  } else {
    _stdout = [];
    _stderr = [];
    encoding = null;
  }
  var stdoutLen = 0;
  var stderrLen = 0;
  var killed = false;
  var exited = false;
  var timeoutId;

  var ex;

  function exithandler(code, signal) {
    if (exited) return;
    exited = true;

    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = null;
    }

    if (!callback) return;

    // merge chunks
    var stdout;
    var stderr;
    if (!encoding) {
      stdout = Buffer.concat(_stdout);
      stderr = Buffer.concat(_stderr);
    } else {
      stdout = _stdout;
      stderr = _stderr;
    }

    if (ex) {
      callback(ex, stdout, stderr);
    } else if (code === 0 && signal === null) {
      callback(null, stdout, stderr);
    } else {
      ex = new Error('Command failed: ' + stderr);
      ex.killed = child.killed || killed;
      ex.code = code < 0 ? uv.errname(code) : code;
      ex.signal = signal;
      callback(ex, stdout, stderr);
    }
  }

  function errorhandler(e) {
    ex = e;
    child.stdout.destroy();
    child.stderr.destroy();
    exithandler();
  }

  function kill() {
    child.stdout.destroy();
    child.stderr.destroy();

    killed = true;
    try {
      child.kill(options.killSignal);
    } catch (e) {
      ex = e;
      exithandler();
    }
  }

  if (options.timeout > 0) {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      kill();
      timeoutId = null;
    }, options.timeout);
  }

  child.stdout.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
    stdoutLen += chunk.length;

    if (stdoutLen > options.maxBuffer) {
      ex = new Error('stdout maxBuffer exceeded.');
      kill();
    } else {
      if (!encoding)
        _stdout.push(chunk);
      else
        _stdout += chunk;
    }
  });

  child.stderr.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
    stderrLen += chunk.length;

    if (stderrLen > options.maxBuffer) {
      ex = new Error('stderr maxBuffer exceeded.');
      kill();
    } else {
      if (!encoding)
        _stderr.push(chunk);
      else
        _stderr += chunk;
    }
  });

  if (encoding) {
    child.stderr.setEncoding(encoding);
    child.stdout.setEncoding(encoding);
  }

  child.addListener('close', exithandler);
  child.addListener('error', errorhandler);

  return child;
};
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, `{encoding: 'binary'}` has no effect. But your `{encoding: 'buffer'}` does not work at all, an exception is thrown at `string_decoder.js:24`: `Error: Unknown encoding: buffer`

Comment: you're right, this code hasn't been released yet. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can you post spawn code that does the same thing as my exec code except that it gets a buffer? I'm not sure how to do this, the docs for spawn don't mention buffers anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! `{encoding: 'buffer'}` works perfect in node v6.2.1.